# Не отображаются данные в WebView

Tags: android

Пытаюсь вывести в `WebView` строку `str = "Hello!";`, но почему-то когда запускаю активити в `WebView` пусто. Пробую так:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "en_US", null);
или так
webView.loadData(str,"text/html", "en_US");
```

На всякий в манифест добавила `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

При этом в логах все отображается, а пробую запускать на Android 9.

Comment: `str` надо форматировать в виде HTML, а не в виде текстовой строки...

Comment: Проблема только с андроид 9, на андроид 8.1 все работает.. Как форматировать в HTML виде строку? в HTML страницу можно и обычный текст выводить ведь.

Comment: Можно обернуть в минимальный набор тегов: `"<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"` - так будет надёжнее. `WebView` обновляется отдельно от системы (как приложение) - поэтому есть вероятность, что проблема проявится не только на Андроид 9, если пользователь установит обновление.

Comment: Разобралась... Проблема была в разметке моей.